# Is there a rasbian host that has the US keyboard by defualt?

Tags: keyboard

I'm sick of having to change the keyboard layout by default to use "|" and "$".

Is there someone out there that takes the most recent distribution and makes in murican'?

Comment: Why is going into the language preferences and changing it to English US such an issue for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you are setting up so many Pi's that it is a real problem you should consider a config management tool like puppet, chef or ansible.

Alternatively, you could make your own. Configure your keyboard etc. then make a new image from your SD card to create additional cards.